# Upload certificate to azure with exportable flag

Tags: azure, certificate, asp.net-web-api2

I want to make Azure WebApp instance (with .Net WebAPI2) to use Google service account certificate.

Steps I went through:

1. Create and download .pfx from Google developers console.
2. Upload .pfx to Azure WebApp -> Custom domains and SSL.
3. Introduce new variable in AppSettings. Key: WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES Value:
   (or thumbprint)

After completing these steps I am getting:
CryptographicException. Key not valid for use in specified state.

One of the reasons I would think of is that it needs an exportable private key, but there are no options (or at least I have not found) to change while uploading it.

I have tested the certificate it works locally.

How to solve this?